# How order a string in alphabetical order in a single row

Tags: excel, vba, string, range, alphabetical

Basically, I have a string with semicolon (;) separated in a Range ("H2"), example (Restrict; No-Resctric; Alpha; Cosmo; n..). This needs to be dynamic, meaning the string may contain more than four words in a single line.

'The expected results should be (Alpha; Cosmo; No-Restrict; Restrict; n..) in the Range ("H2")

Comment: So you have a dynamic string (it may change), but you also want to sort it and put the result back into the cell? It's doable, but usually not a good idea. Is sorting it into a separate cell acceptable?

Comment: Also, which version of Excel? Excel-365 makes a lot of things a bit easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a VBA approach

```
Sub sortCell(inp As Range)
    Dim arr
    arr = Strings.Split(inp.Value2, ";")
    
    Dim sList As Object
    Set sList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        sList.Add CStr(arr(i)), Null
    Next i
    
    Dim result As String
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        result = result & sList.getKey(i) & ";"
    Next i
    
    inp.Value2 = Strings.Left(result, Strings.Len(result) - 1)
End Sub
```

which you could call with, e.g.

```
call sortCell(ActiveSheet.Range("H2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is an **`Excel`** Tag and assume there is no **`Excel Constraints`** this can be accomplished using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=SORT(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,";",1)))
```

---

Or, within the cell:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",,SORT(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,";",1))))
```

---

**Caveat:** Since the output is asked to produce within a cell hence using <kbd>TEXTJOIN()</kbd> there is character limitations i.e. if the **string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit)**, <kbd>TEXTJOIN()</kbd> returns the `#VALUE!` error. Here is the **[MSFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)** documentation. Hence it is better to use `VBA` or split by rows/columns which ever suits with your data.

---

Comment: That's not *(Alpha; Cosmo; No-Restrict; Restrict)* however ;) Ah nvm, you weren't finished with TextJoin

Comment: @Notus_Panda i didn't understand ?

Comment: Nah, you're good, your first solution isn't what OP was going for but the (now edited) Textjoin did the thing. Was a bit too quick on the trigger ^^

Comment: Oh yes I was editing the answer. Sometimes its difficult to understand what OP is asking. Also the first answer i posted because OP said, range and not cell, so may be they are not clear with range and cells!

Comment: OP asked for a solution that sorts it in place, but I agree that this is a better option (see my comment to the question)

Comment: OP sais first: _I have a string with semicolon (;) separated in a Range ("H2"),_  next said _The expected results should be (Alpha; Cosmo; No-Restrict; Restrict; n..) in the Range ("H2")_ so for me in range means byrows or bycolumns that doesnt means in a single cell, OP had to be clear with their post, however i have shown the ways using MS365 function. Also since OP said that can be many then `TEXTJOIN()` function has a character limitations also.

Comment: @Paul I should add a caveat